# How to fix discrepancy in conversions from Google Ads into Google Bigquery via Data Transfer Service for Google Ads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Filtering by conversion name in bigquery and doing the same in google ads, I dont see both match.

Can you please clarify why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

I want to know why this is happening.
I want to know how to fix it.